# Gradle, how to retrieve default resource directory to add a file

Tags: gradle

So, I'm trying to automatically download the native libraries for our [openvr kotlin port](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/openvr).

Using the [Gradle-Download-Task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task) I managed to download the natives (to the build directory):

```
task downloadNatives {
    doLast {
        // download directory listing via GitHub API
        def dirBin = 'https://api.github.com/repos/ValveSoftware/openvr/contents/bin'
        def content_linux32 = new File(buildDir, "directoryContents_linux32.json")
        download {
            src "$dirBin/linux32"
            dest content_linux32
        }        // parse directory listing
        def contents_linux32 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseFile(content_linux32, "utf-8")

        // download files
        download {
            src contents_linux32.collect { it.download_url }
            dest "buildDir/linux32"
        }
```

Now I'd like to put them under the default resource directory, that is `src/main/resources`

I tried to use these:

```
    println sourceSets.main.getResources()
    println sourceSets.main.resources
```

but without much success..

So, what shall I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the second `download` block, `buildDir` is just a string and not a variable.

Then, you can just download the files into the main resources dir :

```
download {
    src contents_linux32.collect { it.download_url }
    dest sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs[0]
}
```

Comment: I get an error on `srcDirs`.. [output](https://gist.github.com/elect86/93911255f1c171b42dad7182e151d5f0)

Comment: `dest sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir[0]`: you miss an "s"